# Php line output

Tags: php, paragraph

I have a file named file.txt that looks like this:

1. Line 1
2. Line 2
3. Line 3
4. Line 4

using the command:

```
$content = file_get_contents(file.txt);
echo $content
```

I get the output on one line:

Line 1  Line 2  Line 3  Line 4

How can I get the output printed over 4 lines?

Comment: [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/nl2br)

Comment: Yes, what is your output medium. Also did you create the file in a different OS then what you are trying to run the code on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually print it to 4 lines but you can't see in it your browser because of parsing as html.

Use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) to add `<br/>`'s

```
$content = file_get_contents(file.txt);
echo nl2br($content);
```

Also you may send [headers](http://php.net/header) that will say that it is not html:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$content = file_get_contents(file.txt);
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo nl2br($content); ?>
```

Replaces all regular line breaks ("\n") with "< br >" tags.

If you just want to show a plain text file you should change the content type to text/plain

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/plain"); ?>
```

Then all linebreaks will be there as they should in a document.